# C# Regex questions

Tags: c#, regex

How can I extract the word "Word" (or any word) using Regex into a string in both cases? in the following string:

```
Word = CreateObject(980, -1696.5996, -12.2998, 5.3, 0, 0, 317.999);

MoveObject(Word, -1660.9004, 79.40039, 2.2,6);
```

I am pretty new in Regex, and I am having hard time understanding the tutorials over the internet.

I have tried using `/(.*)( = CreateObject)/` but no luck

Tried using `/MoveObject\(.*?\,/` and it works, but it matches MoveObject too, and I want it to match only "Word"

Thanks!

Comment: The code above is a string?

Comment: Yes, its the string :)

Comment: What happened to the other question you just posted?  It had a whole history of comments.

Comment: I asked a friend to help me, he tried asking by himself, and now I am trying to explain

Comment: Why not use the regex `"Word"`. You should be more specific on the "rules" of matching...

Comment: @svenssonshirley please do not deface your post. Check out http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251923/what-to-do-when-an-op-asks-to-delete-my-code-from-my-answer/251924#251924 for guidance on similar changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex.

```
@".*?(?= = CreateObject)|(?<=MoveObject\().*?(?=,)"
```

OR

```
@"\S+?(?= = CreateObject)|(?<=MoveObject\().*?(?=,)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mE5cC1/1)

Comment: The both strings are seperate, they can appear anywhere in the text

Comment: @svenssonshirley: that's not a problem, you can instruct the regex engine to return all matches ("captures").

Comment: @svenssonshirley try my update. And the post the string where it fails to match. You could capture the strings you want through capturing groups also.